# Finding entry count for each unique id in SQL

Tags: sql

I have an SQL database that shows the amount of times a person submits an entry. I want to count how many time each person who owns a unique id makes a claim. Each unique i.d can make mulpile entries into the table and I want to find out how many everyone has made.

[image: my data]

I also want to filter the people based on the amount of entries they have made. For example 10.

```
select id, entry, COUNT(ID) from Table where COUNT(entry) <=10 GROUP BY ID
```

This is my thinking so far but I havent had much success. If anyone could help I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Do you want to pick, MySql or SqlServer???

Comment: Please do not post screen shots and try to post repeatable code examples.  Also show what you are getting from your results and what you are expecting.  The query looks pretty accurate but without the above info hard to tell/help out.

Comment: HAVING count(entry) <=10 not WHERE

Comment: select id, entry, COUNT(ID) from Table GROUP BY ID HAVING COUNT(entry) <=10   group by comes before the having

Comment: To display each ID with another column showing the frequency of each, you can use ```select id, count(id) from Table group by id having count(id)<=10 order by id;```. Note that HAVING is used instead of WHERE when dealing with an aggregate clause, i.e. which is GROUP BY in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

This is all you need

```
select id, COUNT(*) cnt
from Table 
GROUP BY ID
having COUNT(*) <= 10
order by 2 desc -- optional descending count
```

Optionally, add  `Order by 2`. `desc` or `asc`